# How to determine the # of decimals in a double?

Tags: c#, math, decimal

If I have a number, how can I determine the number of decimals?

e.g. for 0.0001 I want to get the result 4

> The duplicate suggested above is less suitable than this one because
>   they are taking about culture-independent code but this question is
>   just about decimal oriented code (i.e. after the decimal). So no need
>   to introduce any more overhead:
>
> [Finding the number of places after the decimal point of a Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386672/finding-the-number-of-places-after-the-decimal-point-of-a-double)
>
> but they both are good threads.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386672/finding-the-number-of-places-after-the-decimal-point-of-a-double

Comment: thats how you do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture

Comment: I believe this will be enough:    Math.Abs(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d)))

Comment: I ended up using d.ToString("R").Split('.')[1].Length; from one of the links above. Seems to work and is nice and compact. Maybe not the most efficient way since strings are involved but that doesn't matter for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really. A `double` is a floating point precision data type, so it's never precise.

You *could* hack something around, using `ToString`:

```
double d = 0.994562d;

int numberOfDecimals = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Length
                       - d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).IndexOf('.')
                       - 1
                       ;
```

Comment: ToString is culture dependent. So your hack won't work with a US culture. Better use `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and `.` as decimal mark.

Comment: @dusky: You are right. Edited.