# Rounding to more than 15 decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I am using `Math.Round(decimal d, int decimals)` in C# to round decimals to a specified number of decimal places. I can round **to** 15 decimal places, but when I try and round to 16, for example, I get the following exception:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Rounding digits must be between 0 and 15, inclusive.*

Is there any way of rounding to a higher number of decimal places, perhaps without the use of `Math.Round`?

To give slightly more background to the problem, I am calculating irrational mathematical constants such as 'pi' and 'e', and letting the user specify the number of decimal places to calculate to. The boolean to check whether or not the value and the previous value are identical to the given accuracy is as follows:

```
Math.Round(valuePrevious, decPlaces) == Math.Round(valueCurrent, decPlaces)
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-java-bigdecimal-class-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my variables that were doubles are now BigDecimal but now I can't use Math.Round. Is there any way to round a BigDecimal variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using `Math.Round(decimal d, int decimals)`, you're using `Math.Round(double d, int decimals)`. Make sure that `valuePrevious` is `decimal`, not `double`.

[Doubles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) can be rounded to 15 digits max. [Decimals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) to 28 digits. That's the maximum precision these types support.

Comment: I'll change the values to decimal rather than double. Is there any way of also exceeding decimal's limit of 28 digits? Ideally there would be no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `Decimal.Round()` instead of `Math.Round()`

Decimal.Round supports up to 28 decimal places

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx