# How to check the float decimal point is not longer than 0.00001? C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to limit the user input a number within 5 decimal points(e.g. 0.00007, 1.23456), if user input more than 5 decimal points, it will show a error message.
How can I check it that is it longer than 5 dc?
Thanks

```
public boolean isDc(float userInput)
{
    if(/** if userinput is within 5 dc**/)
         return true;
    else
         MessageBox.show("You should input within 5dc(E.g. 0.00001, 1.12345)");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can convert it to string then split on '.' and check its length.

Comment: A user input is a string.  So you test the string and then convert to a float.

Comment: I don't think this is C#...

Comment: Closely related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387756/643104)

Comment: If you are using c# and you care about the precison of the decimal point then I suggest using `decimal` instead of `float`.

Comment: @timleathart LOL, I forgot `Function` should change `public\private`.

Comment: If you must use `float` code will be very awkward and result in accepting only small subset of values (as only fraction of `float` numbers can be represented with exactly 5 digits after the decimal point)... If `decimal` is ok than suggested duplicate covers it.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I changed to decimal now, ty.

Comment: So "0.12345" is acceptable input, but "0.123450" is excessively precise? If so, you need to inspect the user input, not a converted value as is done in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private Boolean isDc(string userInput)
        {
            var num = Decimal.Parse(userInput); //Use tryParse here for safety
            if (decimal.Round(num, 5) == num)            
                return true;
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You should input within 5dc(E.g. 0.00001, 1.12345)");

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I think you meant `decimal.Round(num, 5)`

Comment: @juharr corrected

Comment: Thank, I added `TryParse` for safety. It work.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you but the `userInput` should be decimal

```
if(BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(userInput)[3])[2] == 5)
{
   //Show the error message
}
```

This will only check that if you have 5 decimal places or not. You can have a look at [Find number of decimal places in decimal value regardless of culture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13493771/3796048) and thus

First way could be

```
public boolean isDc(decimal userInput)
{
    if(BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(userInput)[3])[2] == 5)
         return true;
    else
         MessageBox.show("You should input within 5dc(E.g. 0.00001, 1.12345)");

    return false;
}
```

or

```
public boolean isDc(float userInput)
{
    decimal outdc;
    if(decimal.TryParse(userInput.ToString(), out outdc))
    {
        if(BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(outdc)[3])[2] == 5)
             return true;
        else
             MessageBox.show("You should input within 5dc(E.g. 0.00001, 1.12345)");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Closely related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture) right?

Comment: Yes @un-lucky it is. Added the link. :)